# History of pronunciation of "moiety"

Tags: nouns, pronunciation, history, rhymes

Wiktionary shows the pronunciation of *moiety* as /ˈmɔɪ.ə.ti/, which I think agrees with the audio versions at [merriam-webster.com](http://www.merriam-webster.com/cgi-bin/audio.pl?moiety01.wav=moiety) and [howjsay.com](http://www.howjsay.com/index.php?word=moiety&submit=Submit).  (Be warned that both those links produce audio when clicked.)  Anyhow, from an 1832-vintage quotation for sense 1 at [wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/moiety) (meaning *half*), I have the impression that at some times or places the word has been pronounced with 4 syllables instead of 3, and rhyming with *society*:

> From New Holland the emu,
>           With his better moiety,
>       Has paid a visit to the Zoological Society.

Has its pronunciation changed since then?  Or was this perhaps meant to be merely a [half rhyme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half_rhyme)?

*Edit:* A *[half rhyme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half_rhyme)*, or *near rhyme*, or *imperfect rhyme*, entails consonance on the final consonants of the words involved.  *Moiety* (/ˈmɔɪ.ə.ti/) and *society* (/s@"saI.@.ti/) rise a little above that level, but not to the level of *[perfect rhyme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_rhyme)*, which according to wikipedia's [rhyme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhyme) article, entails having final stressed vowel and all following sounds identical.  But /ɔɪ/ and /aI/ are not identical.

Comment: It's perhaps worth noting that each stanza of the original poem has a different word rhyming with "Society," to include _sobriety_, _anxiety_, and _variety_. (That doesn't your question, I realize, but I think it's interesting and pertinent nonetheless).

Comment: It's also possible the poet did not know how to pronounce the word and merely went by its spelling.

Comment: Daniel Jones (1917) gives 'mɔiəti and 'mɔiiti. John Walker (1791) has "moe1-e1-te1", where e1 stands for long "ee", as in me.

Comment: 'Society' and 'moiety' don't rhyme for you via both their last two syllables __/ə.ti/__?

Comment: Not adequately; see edit re that point

Comment: In 1832, the vowel /aɪ/ in *society* may still have been /ʌi/, which is somewhat closer to /ɔɪ/ than it is now, because the last bit of the [Great Vowel Shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Vowel_Shift) might still have been in progress (it's hard to tell exact dates from the Wikipedia article, especially since these undoubtedly varied greatly between dialects). So the near-rhyme might have been closer.

Comment: Fascinatingly, the same poem's rhyme scheme demonstrates that "zoological" was already pronounced "zoo-ological", almost two decades before the word "zoo" was introduced. (Granted, the poem is very whimsical, so this could have been a joke rather than a reflection of the usual pronunciation; but still, it means the pronunciation must at least have existed.)

Comment: +1 ruakh: whimsical poetry often has pronunciations changed to fit a rhyme.

Comment: @ruakh: the existence of this pronunciation when the word "*zoological*" was shortened is probably why a *"zoo"* is called a *"zoo"* and not a *"zo"*.

Comment: @PeterShor: Prior to seeing this question, I had always assumed that the shortening of <zoological park> to <zoo> /zu/ is what led to the prefix <zoo-> being pronounced /zu@-/. (Short forms often preserve spelling and distort pronunciation, to varying degrees. For example, in computing, *char* (a short form of *character*) is frequently pronounced like *car*; so it retains the /k-/ from *character*, rather than switching to /tS-/, but the vowel pronunciation comes from its spelling rather than its etymon.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the poet spoke a dialect with the [loin-line merger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_English_diphthongs#Line.E2.80.93loin_merger), this would have been an exact rhyme. That is, the 'oi' diphthong in "moiety" would have been pronounced the same as the 'i' in "society". According to the linked webpage, this occurs in some dialects in Southern England, and may have been more widespread when the poem was written.

[This book](http://books.google.com/books?id=U5FDi8WksqYC&pg=PA88&lpg=PA88&dq=%22loin+line%22+meger&source=bl&ots=QSQireWQQe&sig=uxEYy_MxL0_-L17asAlMIJ5zT8o&hl=en&sa=X&ei=SE_0T-j7G8m16wGQq_DCBg&ved=0CEMQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22loin%20line%22%20meger&f=false) says that for some words, the *loin/line* merger was widespread in England in the last half of the 18th century, but "by the end of the century the merger was in retreat, if still acceptable; by the next century spellings like *bile, jine* were provincial stereotypes". So it's possible that a three-syllable *moiety* would have been an exact rhyme for *society* not that long before this poem was written. 
If this merger was widespread enough, or recent enough, that people were used to hearing it, the rhyme would have been reasonable even if the poet didn't use that pronunciation.

EDIT: The pronunciation of the diphthong "i" (now /aɪ/) changed during the Great Vowel Shift, and when it passed "oi" (now /ɔɪ/) during the 18th century, these two diphthongs were close enough that they were merged in the speech of much of the population, and made very good near-rhymes for most of the rest. So rather than *moiety* being pronounced with an /aɪ/, it would have been *society* that was pronounced like *sosoyety*.

Answer (score 0):

In the 19th century, I would expect the "i" to have been printed with a diaeresis (moïety) if it were not part of the oi diphthong.

I see no reason to doubt that this was a poetic device.

Comment: Tolerance72, perhaps you could spell out what ou mean by "this was a poetic device" and also add an explicit IPA form for the pronunciations you refer to, *ie* that of *moïety* and that which you think would follow upon a poetic device.