# The Great Vowel Shift: when did it really end?

Tags: great-vowel-shift

The Wikipedia article states that the Great Vowel Shift ended in 1700:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Vowel_Shift

Why is it, then, that Lord Byron (to pick a name at random) rhymes "I" and "Italy," "good" and "flood," "put" and "but," "move" and "love"?

Comment: I rhyme *blood* and *flood*. And Lord Byron has tons of near-rhymes in his poetry (so many that he couldn't have possibly have pronounced all of them as perfect rhymes). Try looking at Keats' rhymes ... he was much more precise.

Comment: Yes, I rhyme blood and flood. In the North of England you will hear 'put' and 'but' rhyming. I'm pretty sure there's somewhere in England today where 'love' and 'move' rhyme. Do you have a link to where he rhymes 'I' and 'Italy'?

Comment: Peter Shor: I'll definitely get back to you on Keats.

Comment: chasly from UK: I'm sorry about the confusion. My mistake. I meant "blood" and "good," of course. ... "Love" and "move", really? Please clarify: is it luv or loove? Or what? ... As for the link: "Of his departure had been sent him by/His Spanish friends for those in Italy." Don Juan, Canto the Second, Stanza No. 24.

Comment: Peter Shor: Yes, Keats, "Ode to a Nightingale": he rhymes "die" and "ecstasy".

Comment: [Walker's Pronouncing Dictionary of the English Language](https://archive.org/details/walkerspronounc00unkngoog) says they didn't rhyme in 1828. So presumably even Keats used some near-rhymes.

Comment: Peter Shor: Not to be pedantic (I'm just really curious about this one), a near-rhyme is one in which either the stressed vowels, or some of the consonants, are identical. Which is NOT the case here. Now - IF the Shift did indeed end in 1700, then MAYBE there existed some kind of poetic-license tradition to PRONOUNCE some words "the old way"? I'm just guessing here. I really do wonder why this whole "die", "eye", "Italy", "ecstasy" thing has not been researched in depth, since 18th and 19th century English and American poetry are stock full of such rhymes.

Comment: It's a convention perhaps intended to convey an impression of antiquity, to write as rhymes things that used to rhyme, in days past.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eye_rhyme

Comment: Greg Lee: Yes, I would agree, but ... It's okay when such things are done now and then, for style, and not ubiquitously and stubbornly used around the globe by thousands of poets for two centuries. I mean, wouldn't it make the antiquity bit sound like a very old and boring cliche? Poets are supposed to be rebels and all, you know.

Comment: Could you include snippets, the lines,  from Byron poems that use that rhyme?

Comment: Mari-Lou A: No problem:

"Of his departure had been sent him by
His Spanish friends for those in Italy." 

Don Juan, Canto the Second, Stanza No. 24.

Comment: @Ricky: And Keats (in *Ode to a Grecian Urn*) rhymes *morn* and *return*, which was never a rhyme, either before, during, or after the GVS. It's possible that (a) *die* and *ecstasy* were slightly better rhymes in Keats's time than they are today, or (b) the fact that rhymes like this were extensively used by Shakespeare made them permissible as near-rhymes, even though they weren't as close as most common near-rhymes. I don't know how you'd decide between these two cases, though.

Comment: Peter Shor: Please explain how they may have been SLIGHTLY better rhymes. I mean, the way I see it, the vowel in "die" and "ecstasy" can be pronounced as either "ai" or "ee". What am I missing?

Comment: @Ricky: the diphthong in *die* started out as *dee*. It then gradually changed so that at some point it was very close to *doy* (in the early 18th century, Alexander Pope rhymed *join* and *line*, and if it wasn't an exact rhyme it was very close). It eventually ended up as *die*. I don't know whether anybody is sure exactly what happened to the vowel in *ecstasy* and similar words. Is *joy* a slightly better rhyme for *ecstasy* than *die*? I would think so.

Comment: The Wikipedia article says the Great Vowel Shift ended in 1600. It adds that "The changes that happened after 1600 are not usually considered part of the Great Vowel Shift proper." So the vowels were still changing after 1600; just not as fast. It appears that long "i" was still being pronounced as *oy* by a reasonable proportion of the population ca. 1800. [See this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/71378/history-of-pronunciation-of-moiety).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vowels (and consonants) are constantly evolving.  Writing tends to freeze a time period's speech patterns, like a fossil of a life form, but the language continues to evolve.  There was a sound change in Spanish-Portuguese from terra -> tierra, fazenda -> hacienda etc.  Changes are constantly happening.  Why a particular artist in a particular time period made the stylistic choices he or she did is something I don't know.

Comment: Hi LindaK, Welcome to EL&U, while we appreciate your answer, we expect you to put some support/evidence to back up all your claims. It's very important for us all :)